# Я не понимаю, почему инициализатор переменной 'x' 'in.nextInt()' является избыточным

Tags: java

Почему int x = in.nextInt() ни к чему не привязан, хотя в коде он используется

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    in.useLocale(Locale.US);
    int x = in.nextInt();
    int z = 0;
    do{
        x = in.nextInt();
        if (x > 10){
            z = z + x;
            System.out.println(z);
        }
    } while (x % 5 != 0);
    System.out.println(z);
}
```

Comment: Я бы сказал, что она не избыточна, а бессмысленна (если конечно вам не нужно пропустить первое введенное значение): первоначальное значение, указанное при создании переменной `x`, у вас до цикла не используется, и следующее присваивание в цикле затрет это значение. Достаточно просто объявить переменную без инициализации как `int x;`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    in.useLocale(Locale.US);
    int x = in.nextInt(); // первая инициализация
    int z = 0;
    do{
        x = in.nextInt(); // вторая инициализация
        if (x > 10){
            z = z + x;
            System.out.println(z);
        }
    } while (x % 5 != 0);
    System.out.println(z);
}
```

В данном случае у тебя в цикле do/while, происходит инициализация переменной x и цикл do/while гарантирует тебе, что переменной x будет присвоено значение. Так, что да первая инициализация избыточна.